# bound on distance of vectors if bound on their unit vectors is given

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have two distinct non-zero vectors $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|a\|_2 \neq \|b\|_2$ and $a \neq \lambda b$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Also $\|a\|_2 = \alpha_a$ and $\|b\|_2 =\alpha_b$ where $\alpha_a$ and $\alpha_b$ are finite. I have $\epsilon>0$ such that $\|(\frac{a}{\|a\|_2}-\frac{b}{\|b\|_2})\|_2 < \epsilon$. Can we have an upperbound $\delta>0$ such that $\|a-b\|_2 <\delta$ in terms of given constants $\epsilon, \alpha_a \text{ and } \alpha_b$ ?

We can take $\alpha_a,\alpha_b <1$ if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any two such unit vectors $u$ and $v$ with $\delta \equiv ||u-v||_2$, then scaled up versions of those vectors $a\equiv \lambda u$ and $b\equiv \lambda v$ satisfy $||a-b||_2 = ||\lambda(u-v)||_2 = \lambda ||u-v||_2 = \lambda \delta$. By choosing large enough $\lambda$, the quantity $\lambda \delta$ can be made arbitrarily large as long as $\delta \neq 0$.

This shows that for any two directions, we can find vectors in those directions which are arbitrarily far apart even if their unit vectors are close. Hence such an upper bound can't exist.

---

Let's explore the case where the vectors $a$ and $b$ are bounded in length. Suppose you have any two such unit vectors $u$ and $v$ with $\delta \equiv ||u-v||_2$, and define $a\equiv \lambda_1 u$, $b\equiv \lambda_2 v$. Without loss of generality, assume $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2$.

By the triangle inequality and scaling properties of norms,
$$\begin{align*}||a-b|| &= ||\lambda_1 u - \lambda_2 v ||\\ &= ||\lambda_1 u - \lambda_1 v - (\lambda_2-\lambda_1)v ||\\ &\leq ||\lambda_1u-\lambda_1v|| + ||(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)v||\\ &= \lambda_1||u-v|| + (\lambda_2-\lambda_1)||v||\\ &= \lambda_1\delta + (\lambda_2-\lambda_1) \\
&= \lambda_1(\delta-1) + \lambda_2\\
\end{align*}$$

If $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ were allowed to be arbitrarily large, we could make this quantity arbitrarily large. However, if we enforce $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \leq L$ (requiring the length of $a$ and $b$ to each be less than some fixed bound $L$), then we know that this quantity is maximized when $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = L$, in which case its value is

$$\epsilon \equiv L(\delta-1) + L = L\delta.$$

Hence we obtain the desired bound $\epsilon = L\delta$, such that $||a-b|| <\epsilon$ whenever $||\frac{a}{||a||}-\frac{b}{||b||}|| < \delta$ and $||a||,||b|| < L$.

Comment: On reflection, the bound is probably better expressed as $\epsilon \equiv L\cdot \max(\delta, 1)$, since when $\delta < 1$, the upper bound is $L$, while when $\delta \geq 1$, the upper bound is $L\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take any two linearly dependent vectors ($b=\lambda\cdot a$) to find a "counterexample"

EDIT (new condition)

You shall look at this problem geomtrically: fix $a$. The condition you ask on $b$ Requires $b$ to be inside the cone  around the $OA$ line, with vertex at the origin, whose boudary agrees with the intersection of the unit sphere and the $\epsilon$ sphere around $a/\|a\|$. It is then clear that what you ask is clearly impossible, as this cone is unbounded.

This approach is suggested by the fact that the mal $x\mapsto x/\|x\|$ is the projection onto the unit sphere.

Comment: Sorry forgot this case. Thanks for highlighting this special case. I have edited the question.

Comment: See edit for the new approach.

Comment: Thanks. What happens when $\|a\|$ and $\|b\|$ are bounded. I edited the question to incorporate this.